# Facebook alternative interface

Tags: facebook

Has anyone attempted to produce an alternative interface for Facebook using their API? If so, which site is the most complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Facebook.me](http://www.facebook-me.com/) was built with the Graph API from the Facebook team.

It is a minimalistic way to view your profile.

If you an extreme Facebooker this works, you can just direct link to the people you want to see.

The current themes are Rush, PhotoStream and Glide.

I like Rush the best.

```
facebook-me.com/[username]
```

Comment: This domain is now parked with Go Daddy. There's no sign of a new location.

Comment: @AlEverett it's been dead for a while, I can try to dig up the files through archive.org to get it working again, I have also sent one of the creators a message