# Is there a way to change the appearance of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, userscripts

Dear lord it's ugly. The sponsored box, people I know box, not to mention like a dozen other things that I don't use. Has someone "skinned" it with GreaseMonkey? Or actually built an app that just pulls their API and makes it prettier?

No desktop apps (like skype 5.0 please).

Answer (score 4):

**If you are looking to restyle it, the browser extension 'Stylish' (available for Chrome and Firefox, possibly more), is probably your best bet.**

There are 77 pages of styles with the term Facebook designed to be used with Stylish, available here (which can be applied through Greasemonkey too I believe):

http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/all/facebook

Comment: Stylish will also let you further restyle it either by tweaking any of those skins or adding your own... if you're a little adventurous with CSS.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are [a number of Facebook skins](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=facebook+skin&x=0&y=0) you can use with Greasemonkey.  Try out one or two of those, or, if you're Javascript-savvy, look at the source of the script yourself to see if it seems like something you could tweak yourself to your own liking.

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com) is a cool browser app that strips out all the irrelevant junk from your facebook homepage such as the boxes you mentioned that you never use, along with a whole load of other stuff. definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook alternative interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/facebook-alternative-interface)

---

> [Facebook.me](http://www.facebook-me.com/) was bulit with the
>   Graph API from the facebook team.
>
> It is a minimalistic way to view your
>   profile.
>
> [image]
>
> If you an extreme Facebooker this
>   works, you can just direct link to the
>   people you want to see.
>
> The current themes are
>   Rush,PhotoStream and Glide.
>
> I like Rush the best.
>
> ```
> facebook-me.com/[username]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome there are bunch of extensions to change interface of your facebook. I like the one which removes Ads.